# Show that $f^{-1}(F) \in \mathcal F$, for any set $F$ which belongs to the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal A$

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

I'm taking a course on Measure Theory and the following question showed up in my exercises list.

Let $\mathcal F$ be a $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$ and $f$ a function defined on $\Omega$ to $Y$. Let $\mathcal A$ be a collection of subsets of $Y$ such that $f^{-1}(E) \in \mathcal F$ for every $E \in \mathcal A$. Show that $f^{-1}(F) \in \mathcal F$ for any set $F$ which belongs to the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal A$.

I'm having some trouble with it, so I was wondering if anyone could help out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We will show that $M := \{ A \subset Y : f^{-1} (A) \in \mathcal F \}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, because $\mathcal A \subset M$ and if we know that $M$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, we get $\sigma ( \mathcal A ) \subset M$. But that $M$ is a $\sigma$-algebra is self-evident if we know that the preimage operation commutes with basically every other set theroretic operation, in particular:$$f^{-1} \left( \bigcup_n A_n \right) = \bigcup_n f^{-1} (A_n) \quad \text{and} \quad f^{-1} \big(A^\mathrm c\big) = \big( f^{-1} (A) \big)^\mathrm c$$for all $A,A_n \subset Y$.
What we did here is a general approach for proofs about $\sigma ( \mathcal A )$ $-$ you show, that all elements in $\mathcal A$ fulfill whatever property $P$ you desire and then you prove that all subsets $X$ that fulfill that property are a $\sigma$-algebra. Because $\sigma ( \mathcal A )$ is, by definition, the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing $\mathcal A$, you're done.